# Architecture of site specific search engine and web crawler

Tags: web-crawler, search-engine

Can someone let me know an architecture of site specific search engine as in very general answer, I don't want any coding and other stuff just as a theory.

Second doubt I have is: in an effort to crawl web pages faster, you set up two different crawling machines with different starting seed URLs. The two crawling computers are not set up to communicate with each other and share data. Is this an effective strategy for distributed web crawling?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: The second part sounds like a homework assignment. Can you be more specific about why you are asking these questions? If you are wanting to build something, what do you want to build exactly? What architecture do _you_ think it should have?

Answer (score 0):

well firstly, if the two computers where not connected in anyway, then how do you deal with recording the same webstes multiple times, youre best shot would be to link them and use there combined resources(you can probably find some free software to do this, im not sure from my own experience).
Secondly, your question is very vague, search engines have three main parts, the web crawling, the indexing and db and all that and then the front end, the user sees just the front end, typically in php just like youre average website. the indexing and db related stuff is where you organise your data in the db, and then the web crawling is where you collect the data. It really is very simple at that level of abstraction, but without a more detailed question we really cannot go deeper.